# Is it possible to send message in inputData for ERC20 contracts?

Tags: erc-20, raw-transaction, hex

There is a transaction on the Rinkeby testnet that has a message encoded in the input data of the transaction

`https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x19e4921d572e7f513954c9dada66d7e4fb01d91b5c09be840b235c9fae73401e`

The message reads `Agorism is happening. Ethereum is the counter-economy.`. Is it possible to add a message as input data when sending an ERC20 contract to another user, or is the input data required to be unmodified for the smart contract `Transfer()` function to be called correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ERC20 standard does not have functionality to transfer tokens with arbitrary input data.

However, you can always add extra functionality to your ERC20 contract. There are also some ERC standards which add such functionality, but can't remember which.

If you add a custom function in your ERC20 token contract, you can call it and it will work just fine, but the problem is that third parties will possibly not understand the new function, and especially won't be able to utilize the function since it's not part of the standard.

Depending on the external service, they may record the ERC20 transfer just fine as long as you emit the `Transfer` event in the new function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I am handling other people's ERC20 tokens (eg WETH, USDT)